# No references with biber/biblatex under TexLive

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'am using a current TexLive version to generate references in my slides. But after switching to TexLive (from the Ubuntu packages) my references do not appear anymore in the slide. Here a NMWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bib_rosetta}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{refsection}%
        \nocite{neyman_use_1928}
        \nocite{radhakrishna_rao_large_1948}
        \nocite{wald_tests_1943}
        \printbibliography%
    \end{refsection}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I get a warnings during compilation, e.g.

```
Prozess gestartet: biber "mwe"

INFO - This is Biber 2.4
INFO - Logfile is 'mwe.blg'
INFO - Reading 'mwe.bcf'
WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 3.3, expected version 3.0
```

but a "mwe.bbl" is generated, but during compilation it appears

```
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Warning: File 'mwe.bbl' is wrong format version - expected 2.8
...
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'wald_tests_1943' undefined on input line 14.
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 14.
```

So I guess biblatex can not read the mwe.bbl correctly. How can I update biblatex such that it works? I tried already to update my TeXLive as root

```
cd install-tl-20170314/
tlmgr update --self
tlmgr update --all
```

but this did not help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to clean the .bcf and .bbl and rerun LaTeX, afterwards rerun biber?

Comment: Your biber is too old (or your biblatex too new).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I think this might be caused, because he run biber on Ubuntu which doesn't ship the most recent TeXLive (if I'm not mistaken), while biblatex was used on a system with a more recent TeXLive. Therefore I advised to try cleaning and rebuilding.

Comment: @Skillmon For the MWE I created a fresh mwe.tex. And you are right, I use an experimental feature of xparse which was just published in March 2017, therefore I installed TexLive myself at the mid of march.

Comment: Did you also install a recent biber? At least on Arch-Linux biber is not inside the texlive-distro but a package on its own.

Comment: Could it be that there are some remnants of the old installation left on your system? What do you get for `kpsewhich -all biblatex.sty`? Check that the path lines up with your new installation. If you get more than one match, there is another `biblatex.sty` floating around.

Comment: @Skillmon The same is true for Ubuntu, biber comes from the package repositories. I'll try to install a newer version of biber then I will see if it works.

Comment: @moewe Just one match from texlive.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was caused by a version mismatch of `biblatex` and Biber that was resolved by updating all packages involved.

Answer (score 0):

After updating my Ubuntu to the most recent version (17.04) I downloaded the current [biber](http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/) version (2.7), extracted it and run it on my example and the references appear now :)

Thanks to everybody for help

Comment: Normally, you should not download and install packages manually. That should always be done via your TeX distribution and its facilities. Remember to update Biber when you (or your distribution) update(s) `biblatex`.